# Simple combinatorics - inclusion and exclusion problem

Tags: combinations, inclusion-exclusion

There are 3 groups ${{A}_{1}},{{A}_{2}},{{A}_{3}}$ 
What we know about them :
\begin{align}
  & |{{A}_{1}}|=|{{A}_{2}}|=|{{A}_{3}}|=n \\ 
 & |{{A}_{1}}\cup {{A}_{3}}|=2n-q \\ 
 & {{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{2}}\subseteq {{A}_{3}} \\ 
 & |{{A}_{2}}\cup {{A}_{3}}|=2n-p \\ 
\end{align}
I need to find out the $|{{A}_{1}}\cup {{A}_{2}}\cup {{A}_{3}}|$ =? (only depend on n,p,q)

So what I did :
\begin{align}
  & |{{A}_{1}}\cup {{A}_{3}}|=|{{A}_{1}}|+|{{A}_{3}}|-|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|=2n-q \\ 
 & 2n-|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|=2n-q \\ 
 & |{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|=q \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & |{{A}_{2}}\cup {{A}_{3}}|=|{{A}_{2}}|+|{{A}_{3}}|-|{{A}_{2}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|=2n-p \\ 
 & 2n-|{{A}_{2}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|=2n-p \\ 
 & |{{A}_{2}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|=p \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & |{{A}_{1}}\cup {{A}_{2}}\cup {{A}_{3}}|=|{{A}_{1}}|+|{{A}_{2}}|+|{{A}_{3}}|-|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{2}}|-|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|-|{{A}_{2}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|+|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{2}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|= \\ 
 & 3n-|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{3}}|-q-p+|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{2}}\cap {{A}_{3}}| 
\\ 
\end{align}

What I know from the fact that : \begin{align}  |{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{2}}|\subseteq {{A}_{3}} \end{align}

is that \begin{align}  \|{{A}_{1}}\cap {{A}_{2}}|\le n\ \end{align}, 
And I don't know how to continue

Comment: It's probably easiest to try and portray this as a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|A_1 \cup A_3|=2n-q \implies A_1$ and $A_3$ have $q$ items in common.

$|A_2 \cup A_3|=2n-p \implies A_2$ and $A_3$ have $p$ items in common.

$A_1 \cap A_2 \subseteq A_3 \implies A_1$ and $A_2$ have no common items that are not also common to $A_3$.

Therefore, $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3|=3n-q-p$.

Answer (score 0):

The in-and-out formula for three sets:
$$|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|=|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-|A_1\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_3|-|A_2\cap A_3|+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|.$$
However, since $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3=A_1\cap A_2$, this simplifies to
$$|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|=|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-|A_1\cap A_3|-|A_2\cap A_3|$$
which as you know is equal to $3n-q-p$.